# XAMPP localhost - phpmyadmin cant be reached after changing OS to windows 10 pro 2019

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, xampp, laragon

I installed windows 10 pro-2019 2 weeks back and I've been trying to build a website using WordPress but I'm facing a lot of trouble with both XAMPP and Laragon web servers.

> localhost/PHPMyAdmin can't be reached.

Everything seems fine, I don't see any errors but it just won't load the phpmysql page.

XAMPP Apache is already running on port 80
XAMPP Apache is already running on port 443
XAMPP MySQL is already running on port 3306

Comment: If I were you, I will re-install XAMPP. Be sure to backup the DB data using MySQL workbench first.

Comment: check your hosts file